# Add onclick listener to Icon on ActionBar in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, android-actionbar, icons

[image: LoginActivity]

I have a settings icon on my Action Bar and I wanted to do something when the user taps on icon as shown in the picture below(e.g display toast), I just need the method that's all, Thanks in advance...Here is the code that created inflates the icon to my ActionBar

```cs
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.settings, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Xml code for the menu item

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item1"
          android:icon="@drawable/settings"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Method to handle when that icon is clicked is greatly appreciated(Display Toast)

Comment: Did you try override `OnContextItemSelected` and check if that is triggered?

Comment: No I did not, does the method need any parameters?Is it boolean? Can you post the whole method as a comment?, Thanks

Comment: Or the compiler will auto complete code?

Comment: I found the method, thats an upvote for you already, Thanks

Comment: ```public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            return base.OnContextItemSelected(item);
        }```  Should i comment the super?

Comment: ```public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You tapped on the Settings Icon", ToastLength.Long).Show();
           return base.OnContextItemSelected(item);
        }``` It didnt work

Answer (score 0):

This *inbuilt* method works to display a toast when the settings icon is tapped

```
 public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "You tapped on the Settings Icon", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```